# My git controlled files cannot revert

Tags: git

Whenever I run `git commit` or `git status`, there are some files I never changed before pop up showing `modified`. I checkout/revert these files, but it does not work. `git diff` also shows no difference.

I notice that whenever I run `git checkout` or `git revert` on the file I do not changes, its modify time changes.

Is there any way I can revert these unchanged file to the origin state?

Below is my git bash output, I remove some outputs because many files are now in incorrect state. You can see the file 'repositories.config' cannot revert.

> Welcome to Git (version 1.9.4-preview20140611)
>
> Run 'git help git' to display the help index. Run 'git help '
>   to display help for specific commands.
>
> [MyAccount] /d/Git/Tour/Visa/Order/Visa.Order.Main/packages (release)
>
> **$ git status**
>
> On branch release Your branch is up-to-date with
>   'origin/release'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>     modified:   repositories.config
> ```
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
>
> [MyAccount]  /d/Git/Tour/Visa/Order/Visa.Order.Main/packages (release)
>
> **$ git checkout .**
>
> [MyAccount]  /d/Git/Tour/Visa/Order/Visa.Order.Main/packages (release)
>
> **$ git status**
>
> On branch release Your branch is up-to-date with
>   'origin/release'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>     modified:   repositories.config
> ```
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Can you paste the exact output of `git status` here?

Comment: Could be a problem with automatic conversion of line ending characters. Is `core.autocrlf` on?

Comment: Did you push the changes live? I believe things show up as "modified" until even after commit until you `git push`

Comment: @stholzm , yes, it's on. and all of my team members use windows platform.

Comment: @Matthew , it's not my change, why should I commit or push it? And when my colleagues pull the branch, they encounter the same problem: the same files show changed, and revert/checkout do not work.

Comment: @BartMao, you can use `git cat-file` to crawl through the repository and see how the file in question is stored as blob. Then compare it with the file in the working directory. There should be a difference. This link might help: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Another possibility are file permissions that cannot be applied on Windows, so the file shows up as "modified" even if the content is the same. Does `git config core.fileMode false` make a difference?

Comment: @Matthew, "modified" means the file differs from the index. It is not affected by pushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it was the file **.gitattributes** changed the git behavior.
This file includes the below line:
* text=auto,
which will automatically normailize line endings. So comments this line with '#', everything goes fine.
Check http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes for more details.

> ## Set to string value "auto"
>
> When text is set to "auto", the path is
>   marked for automatic end-of-line normalization. If Git decides that
>   the content is text, its line endings are normalized to LF on checkin.

Actually there are many things that can affect the git behavior on line endings check. git config: core.autocrlf, core.safecrlf, core.whitespace. If encounter such similar problem, you can check all these aspects.